# In SwiftUI, how would I make a function that adds an item to a ScrollView?

Tags: c, swift, swiftui

```
@_cdecl
func AddItemToScrollView(TheString:UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> Void {
    //How would I go about doing something like this
}

import SwiftUI
struct Example: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            //...
        }
    }.onAppear () {
        FunctionThatWouldCallAddItemToScrollViewABazillionTimes()
    }
}
```

You get the idea about what I am trying to do. I want an external file to determine when items are added in the form of text to a ScrollView. How would I go about doing this? So... Yeah. My goal is to have a ScrollView, and items are added by an external C file calling a function. Don't worry about `TheString`, for starters I want a function that will add just a "Hello, World!" text to the scrollview every time it is called. I can figure the rest out from there, so all I need is help on how to go about doing this.

*How shall I proceed?*

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/timothycosta/0d8f64afeca0b6cc29665d87de0d94d2) to Add `Subviews` using `ScrollView` in `SwiftUI`

```
import SwiftUI
struct UIScrollViewWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
var content: () -> Content
init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
self.content = content
    }
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIScrollViewViewController {
let vc = UIScrollViewViewController()
        vc.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(self.content())
return vc
    }
func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIScrollViewViewController, context: Context) {
        viewController.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(self.content())
    }
}
class UIScrollViewViewController: UIViewController {
lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
let v = UIScrollView()
        v.isPagingEnabled = true
return v
    }()
var hostingController: UIHostingController<AnyView> = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
self.pinEdges(of: self.scrollView, to: self.view)
self.hostingController.willMove(toParent: self)
self.scrollView.addSubview(self.hostingController.view)
self.pinEdges(of: self.hostingController.view, to: self.scrollView)
self.hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
func pinEdges(of viewA: UIView, to viewB: UIView) {
        viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewB.addConstraints([
            viewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.leadingAnchor),
            viewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.trailingAnchor),
            viewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.topAnchor),
            viewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: Why we would need to use a UIScrollView ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the same view (maybe with minor modifications), you could use a ForEach view with a state variable:

```
@State private var viewCount: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(0..<viewCount) { index in
            YourView() //maybe 'index' or '$index' is an input parameter.
        }
    }
}
```

then you implement the way you want to increase the `viewCount`. Although if `YourView` is implemented without SwiftUI, it must be wrapped in a `UIViewRepresentable`-conforming view.

Comment: I havent tested it yet, I am implementing testing it, but I will accept it if it is helpful.